# Global .scss file in the ASP.NET Core 2 Angular project

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, sass

I have a problem with using SASS with ASP.NET Core 2.0 Angular template. I implemented SASS like it's described here:
https://brettthewhitt.com/2017/10/27/implementing-sass-in-angular-core-2-visual-studio-template/
and I can now easily use .scss files instead of .css files in the components. But I'd like to have also one global scss file where I can store global styles, variables, mixins etc.
I tried to create global.scss file and include it in the boot.browser.ts like this:

```
require("!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!./styles/global.scss");
```

with this approach styles work globally but I don't have access to sass variables in other sass files. How could I make it to have one global.scss file with global styles and variables, mixins that I can use in other scss files?

Comment: Try importing the global.scss file on to the other scss files and then you should be able to access the sass variables & mixins.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's exactly what I've done for now, but I think there should be better solution for this.

Comment: I do agree that there should be a better solution than importing global scss file on to all other scss files. If you find  a better approach please do update it here.

Comment: Sure, I will if I find something better.

Comment: Did you find a better solution?

Comment: I didn't, I just sticked to importing global scss file to other files